# Javascript/Ajax - download file automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download

On the click of a button I make an ajax call , a csv-file is created, and a link to the file is returned. On success, I want the file to download.

If on success I do:

```
 window.open(output);
```

a new window opens and I can see the correct path to the file in the adress bar. But I get a 404 error, so it is interpreted as a page rather than a file download.

With html links you can use "download" to achieve a file download:

```
<a href="/path.jpg" download>
```

Is there some equivalent command in javascript to achieve this download?

------------------------**Edit:**-----------------------------

It turned out that

```
window.open(output);
```

works fine! I used the file system path instead of the URL - I needed to use the url. Now when I click the button, the file downloads at the ajax success method.

(if this question is not unique I can delete it if you think so)

Comment: even with the new window, it should not return a 404. Your server doesn't know how the client is handling the file and would send it regardless what's happening on the other side. A 404 always indicates a wrong URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Axel Amthor yes, I see that you are right, the URL seems to be the file system path but needs to be the url...I will try it.